# "UnetStack libraries missing" error received when trying to run UnetStack simulation script from command line

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to run my UnetStack simulation script using command line. My simulation file is in the sample folder, and I open a terminal window in the `unet` folder (where README.txt exists). I followed the README.txt instructions, and I tried to run other simulations script from the sample folder, but I always get the following error:

> ERROR: UnetStack libraries missing...

However, everything works well if I run the simulation using IDE. I will be grateful if you help sort out this problem, so I run the simulation through command line.

I tried to run the simulation script using command line. I followed README. txt instructions, but it didn't work.

I tried this: `bin/unet samples/super-tdma/e3-network.groovy` and many other simulation scripts.

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

This is to make sure that my question has been posted, as I can't see it within the listed questions.

Comment: You missed tagging the question with a `unetstack` tag. I've proposed an edit to add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use v1.3 or
In v1.4, Copy all the Items from the folder "UnetID" to the "root folder", then run the simulation.